# How to store multiple return values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return

I just came to know that in Python 3.5 we can return multiple values.
So I tried to work out a piece of code that can use this feature , But the problem is that how do I store these multiple values? Kindly refer to the followig code.

```
def input1():
    stu=input("Enter Student Name")
    marks=int(input("Enter Student marks"))
    return stu,marks

def assign():
    s=[]
    m=[]
    i=0
    while True:
        #s[i],m[i]=input1()
        a=int(input("0 to exit"))
        i+=1
        if a==0:
            print(s)
            print(m)
            break
```

`stu` is a string and `marks` is an integer.
I want to store both the values simultaneously in the arrays `s[]` and `m[]`.
Just below the while block is the syntax I intended to use, but it obviously doesn't work.

Output:

```
Enter Student NameR
Enter Student marks45

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "School_Rank.py", line 19, in <module>
        assign()
    File "School_Rank.py", line 12, in assign
        s[i],m[i]=input1()
    IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: Looks like it should work to me. What's the error?

Comment: List index is out of range, @cricket_007. Ritesh, edit your question and provide the full traceback Python prints for you.

Comment: Also, `a == 0` will never be True, `a` is always a string. (you'll need to `int()` it).

Comment: Your problem isn't with multiple return values. It's with trying to assign to the elements of an empty list.

Comment: Just guessing here because of your incomplete question/code...s[0], m[0] = input1()  just as an example for you to think about.                                                        Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read The Tour and refer to the material from the Help Center what and how you can ask here. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example that reproduces your problem, and mention error messages verbatim in your question.

Comment: a==0 fixed Jim, thanks for the help. Yes the problem was assigning to an empty list. I'm sorry for not providing the output and I'll definitely go through the Tour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is:

```
s_var,m_var=input1()
s.append(s_var)
m.append(m_var)
```

You have a problem assigning a value to an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

These "multiple values" in the return statement is actually a tuple. So, you can assign each value of the returned tuple into two identifiers and then append these values into the lists. Here's a piece of code:

```
def input1():
    stu = input('Enter student name: ')
    marks = input('Enter student marks: ')

    return stu, marks


def assign():
    s = []
    m = []

    stu, marks = input1()
    s.append(stu)
    m.append(marks)
    .#etc...
```

You're getting an error because you're trying to access the position i and then set its value to whatever you want when the position i doesn't exist yet. I hope I helped you.